# Relation between signal mixer and filters

Tags: rf, ac, filter, signal, mixer

Mixer output shown as red wave:

[image: MixerOutput]

Can a band-pass filter be used to remove the low frequency shown as a blue sine wave and leave the rest high frequency just like the frequency shown as a green sine wave? If so, which band-pass filter provides the most proper output (most relatable with the green wave?) RC or RLC filters? Active or passive filters?

I want the filter to be compatible with 2 different frequency values to distinguish frequency-modulated waves while showing high impedance to lower or higher frequencies.

An RC bandpass filter outputs a low voltage of the red sine wave if I'm not mistaken

- Bandpass filter's input - red sine wave
- Bandpass filter's output - green sine wave
- Removed frequency - blue sine wave

The circuit I got the screenshot:

[image]

The circuit I am up to:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think it is good if you tell: 1. how much do you know about what exactly is bandpass filter. 2. What is the difference between active and passive filter. I think if you understand this two question then your problem will solve, am I right?

Comment: The red signal is not the sum of the blue and green signals. So, removing the blue signal from the red signal will not leave the green signal.

Comment: bandpass filters can be used to block undesired frequencies if the pass-band of the filter is narrow enough. However, as I mentioned, the red signal is not the sum of the blue and green signals. So when you pass the red signal through a bandpass filter, the result will not be the green signal. Where are you getting these signal images from?

Comment: Deleted cause  I wanted to ask a new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624113/whats-the-purpose-of-the-band-pass-filter-in-rf-transmiter

Comment: That block diagram and a DB-hz chart related to a bandpass filter got me thinking the relation between mixers and bandpass filter works that way. Mixer sums carrier wave with a signal which corresponds to a green sine wave and also subtracts which corresponds to the blue sine wave than as a result mixer outputs the red signal. Then you choose which frequency whether subtracted or summed.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the red wave is what the mixer output should be.

Comment: I guess that band-pass filter has nothing to do with mixer output but "Preventing the transmitter from emitting additional frequencies that are out of band"

Comment: "Mixer sums carrier wave with a signal". No it doesn't merely _sum_ the components. The original signals do appear in the result, but the result also includes the "multiplication" of the original signals.

Comment: Didn't get from anywhere. Screenshotted ltspice oscilloscope screen while trying to figure out how mixers and bandpass filters work with each other.

Comment: Question Updated.

Comment: Thanks. Great! :-) Now I don't know where V(n007), V(n010) and V(n012) are taken from (although I can guess). But can you see that there is probably no reason to believe that  V(n007) is the sum of the other two? Also, you previously asked whether the "red" signal is the appropriate output of the mixer. Yes it is. It might be tweeked, but it is essentially what you might want to see.

Comment: Noo. I believe that the red wave consists of 2 sine waves. Sum of 110khz and 100khz which is 220khz(green sine wave). And subtraction of 110khz and 100khz which is 10khz(blue sine wave).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137194/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-lucassokol).

Comment: Then mixer output can be directly connected to an antenna after amplifying?

Comment: The mixer output has the sum and difference frequencies, so you need some form of filter to pick out which one you want and to filter out any other out of band frequencies - so usually a bandpass filter. For RF, it would usually be a LC filter, for lower frequencies a RC filter, maybe active. Note that in modern circuitry most of the processing is done by DSP. Nevertheless you need some form of physical filter on the inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diode ring mixer used in your previous question can generate *amplitude modulation* suitable for radio-frequency transmission.
The example shown uses a sine wave **V_carrier**, frequency of 50 MHz. This could also be a square wave source as well. Amplitude is about 1.5V RMS. These mixers work well when driven with a source resistance of 50 ohms. The carrier signal generator should be capable of delivering roughly +10 dBm - that's 10 milliwatts into 50 ohms.

The modulating signal here **V_baseband** is 1 MHz sine wave, amplitude of 0.2V with a 0.2V DC offset. When this generator is at 0V, no RF output appears. When amplitude rises to +0.2V, maximum RF output appears. These modulators can usually accept baseband input frequency of many megahertz. It needn't be a sine wave - digital signals can be applied too, as long as they can drive 50 ohms. Be aware that the carrier frequency should be far higher than the frequency of this baseband signal, to ease the requirement of the output filter needed to knock down harmonics.
[image: schematic AM modulator]

The output signal **AM_radio_frequency_output** contains harmonics, mostly at 3x carrier frequency (at 150 MHz) and above. These should be attenuated. This is usually done with a band-pass filter, centered at the carrier frequency (in this example 50 MHz).[image: AM_radio_frequency_output waveform]
[image: AM modulator spectrum showing all harmonics]

 These modulators are standard components made by various manufacturers which are to remain un-named. Many allow the modulating source to go down to DC, as shown in the schematic above. No need to build one yourself.

 But be aware that output is feeble, and likely needs amplification before driving an antenna. And don't forget the bandpass filter, else those harmonics will cause problems for other spectrum users.

 In this example, the bandpass filter should have a bandwidth of at least twice the modulating frequency (2 MHz). A low-pass filter would work too, with 50 MHz at the upper end of the pass-band, and 150 MHz in the stop-band. At these frequencies, LC filters are appropriate.